# Cordova/PhoneGap: App crashes using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am using the following code to display the users location using the Google maps API:

```
//GEOLOCATION
            var onSuccess = function(position) {
                alert('Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude   + '\n' +
                      'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude  + '\n');

                var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
                var myLong = position.coords.longitude;

                //MAP
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong),
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                              mapOptions);

            };

            // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
            //
            function onError(error) {
                alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            }

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

The map and correct location shows up for a second and then the app crashes. Can any one tell me whats going on at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. There was a piece of code on another page conflicting with this one - I did not know that this could occur so didnt clean it up.